# webmethod not working using ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, jquery, webmethod

my .cs code is

```
auth_reg.aspx.cs (breakpoint shows the method is never reached)
[WebMethod]
public void ImageButton1_Click()
{
    string strScript = "<script language='JavaScript'>alert('working')</script>";
    Page.RegisterStartupScript("PopUp", strScript);
}
```

.html code

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnsave" runat="server" Text="Submit" ImageUrl="images/btn-submit1.jpg" src="images/btn-submit1.jpg" onmouseout="this.src='images/btn-submit1.jpg';" onmouseover="this.src='images/btn-submit.jpg';" />

 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#imgbtnsave').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "auth_reg.aspx/ImageButton1_Click",
            data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert('workingajax');
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('error');
            }
        });          
    });
</script>
```

my code is not calling, page just simply get refresh on click

Comment: did you find an answer?

Comment: asing ashx page we can do this

Answer (score 3):

A page method must be static:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void ImageButton1_Click()
{

}
```

But you cannot register client script method in a Page Method because it is static.

besides the image control is a server side control so the jQuery selector must be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#<%=imgbtnsave.ClientID%>").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "auth_reg.aspx/ImageButton1_Click",
            data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert('workingajax');
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('error');
            }
        });          
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your WebMethod Static and fix your mistake using the following code:

```
$("#<%=imgbtnsave.ClientID%>").click(function () {
    var para1;
    var para2;
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: 'EXAMPLE.aspx/SaveData',
    data: "{'para1':'" + para1+ "', 'para2':'" + para2+ "'}",
    async: false,
    success: function (response) {
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log('there is some error'); }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with classic asp.net, but I think you should put your click handler in the [`ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) statement, because the problem might be that the JavaScript is executed before the DOM is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#imgbtnsave').click(function () {
    ...
  });
});
```

And besides that, check your console (e.g. FireBug of Chrome Dev tools) to see if there are JavaScript errors.

Comment: You can change your error function to: `function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
}`

Comment: i have put that code and now it ia showing Request failed:error

Comment: Hmm.. I don't have any more options then. Maybe your `data` argument is wrong, since it's empty you can remove it and try again. Also verify if a call is being made (in the network panel of FireBug) and if the request doesn't return a 404 status code.

Comment: i console error such as "Expected 'none' or URL but found 'Alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped." is coming

Answer (score 0):

1st make your Web Method static and if your method is still not firing then please make sure the url in $.ajax call is correct

url: "/auth_reg.aspx/ImageButton1_Click",`

put "/" at the front or debug it on firebug that the url is correct or not